# SignalR (Azure). Determine reason of why user got disconnected

Tags: azure, signalr

We have SignalR service hosted on Azure.

For technical reasons, it is essential for us to maintain as stable connection between client and host as possible. And what is happening is that at relatively random intervals some clients got disconnected. We know that this is not related to internet connectivity on the clients's side.

So, the question is, how we can determine reason of a disconnect. 
Our SignalR hub implements overrides 'OnDisconnectedAsync'. And this method has 'Exception exc' parameter. Unfortunately every time it get's triggered, exc is always null (I was hoping to find details for disconnect there).

Additional details:
We user following SignalR packages on Server side:
Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR (2.4.0)
Microsoft.Azure.SignalR (1.0.5)

On client side we use "Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.Core" (1.1.0)

Also, we checked and we have enough resources on Azure SignalR (units)

Here are logs when user gets disconnected (happen after OnDisconnectedAsync):
2020-03-15 11:38:07.391 +00:00 [Debug] Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.HubConnectionHandler: OnConnectedAsync ending.
2020-03-15 11:38:07.391 +00:00 [Debug] Microsoft.Azure.SignalR.ServiceConnection: Sending close connection message to the service for GFf8suySt2eMsOCLuYg0-wbb16618b1.
2020-03-15 11:38:07.391 +00:00 [Debug] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.Internal.WebSocketsTransport: Received message from application. Payload size: 36.
2020-03-15 11:38:07.393 +00:00 [Debug] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.Internal.WebSocketsTransport: Message received. Type: Binary, size: 37, EndOfMessage: True.
2020-03-15 11:38:07.393 +00:00 [Debug] Microsoft.Azure.SignalR.ServiceConnection: Received 37 bytes from service 12aa875c-a5b6-4842-8bc1-2d67e7ab30f6.
2020-03-15 11:38:07.393 +00:00 [Debug] Microsoft.Azure.SignalR.ServiceConnection: Connection GFf8suySt2eMsOCLuYg0-wbb16618b1 ended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the client is connected to the Azure SignalR, the persistent connection between the client and Azure SignalR can sometimes drop for different reasons. This section describes several possibilities causing such connection drop and provides some guidance on how to identify the root cause.

**Possible errors seen from the client-side:**

- The remote party closed the WebSocket connection without completing the close handshake
- Service timeout. 30.00ms elapsed without receiving a message from service.
- {"type":7,"error":"Connection closed with an error."}
- {"type":7,"error":"Internal server error."}

**Root cause:**

Client connections can drop under various circumstances:

- When Hub throws exceptions with the incoming request.
- When the server connection the client routed to drops, see below section for details on server connection drops.
- When a network connectivity issue happens between client and SignalR Service.
- When SignalR Service has some internal errors like instance restart, failover, deployment, and so on.

Please refer to https://github.com/Azure/azure-signalr/blob/dev/docs/tsg.md#client-connection-drops